# Special keyboard keys

Tags: keyboard, java

I have this applet made in java, which relies on the users keycode input.
The case is that I have to press "Insert" for a function, which doesn't exist on the keyboard. Another function requires the "Page Up", which is also missing from my keyboard.

I have the BT Keyboard (no numpad).

I did not make the applet and there are no options to change the keyboard-controls.

How can I send these 'keys' to the Java applet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page up Key is mapped to <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow UP</kbd>.

Other key combinations with fn and the arrow keys are:

- <kbd>Arrow down</kbd> > page down
- <kbd>Arrow left</kbd> > beginning of line or begin of page depending on situation
- <kbd>Arrow right</kbd> > end of line or bottom of page depending on situation

For the Insert Key there's no correspondant key on a Mac keyboard, but you could try using the <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> which I found [here](http://flanders.co.nz/2008/08/11/finally-found-the-insert-key-on-my-macbook-pro-keyboard/). I can't confirm this though as I absolutely have no idea where I could test this out.

Comment: fn + Enter didn't work, but fn + Up did.

Comment: fn+Enter is a Windows key combination for Insert, if you've installed it on your Mac (like with BootCamp).

Answer (score 2):

On that keyboard, the Page-Up key code can be sent by pressing:
<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>

This can be found by turning on the Keyboard Viewer in System Preferences -> Language and Text -> Input Sources.